# Inconsistent Elassandra cluster state after node restart - less data on one node

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, data-consistency, elassandra

I have migrated my existing data in 4 nodes Cassandra (with RF=3) to Elassandra and after putting my mappings whole data got indexed into Elassandra. After the completion of indexing, all nodes show a consistent result in `/_cat/indices?v` API. But as soon as I restart any node the data on that node is reduced substantially, index size as well as the number of records. If I restart another node of the cluster the problem shift to that node and previous node recovers automatically. For more details and detailed use case please refer [to the issue](https://github.com/strapdata/elassandra/issues/331) I have created with Elassandra.

Comment: Please share the index settings, especially the shard and replica count

Comment: No. of shards=4, replica count=2. I have shared the full cluster details in the issue I logged with Elassandra. I was able to reproduce this on 10 shards, 2 replica setup as well. The concerned index name is cmsentitydb. Please check the file attached https://github.com/strapdata/elassandra/files/4226477/cluster-state.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade to Elassandra v6.8.4.3 has resolved the problem. Thanks!